# How use Flash[:notice] to notify while using Backup Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using backup gem to create backup of pg DB,  can we use notify to display flash message as the backup complete instead of notifying by Mail. Or any other way to define custom notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Flash messages generally help when you **redirect from controller** for which **nothing is rendered**. Suppose you want to create a user. Now if create controller is not rendering anything, rather it is redirecting to home page, you can use flash messages here. Given below is the syntax for that.

```
flash[:notice] = "User successfully created"
```

or

```
flash[:notice] = "Some error occured"
```

based on the condition flash message will be displayed on next page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"The on_success, on_warning and on_failure notifications are always true by default."

```
notify_by Mail do |mail|
  mail.on_success = false
  mail.on_error = false
  mail.on_failure = false
  #flash[:notice] = 'Done...' or whatever
end
```

Like Singh said, the messages are for the user to know what is going on.  With the backup gem you do not need to notify the user about the backups, unless it is used for server admins or something like that.

Or you can override notify

```
module Backup
  module Notifier
    class Mail < Base
      #....
      def notify!(status)
        name, send_log =
            case status
            when :success then [ 'Success', false ]
            when :warning then [ 'Warning', true  ]
            when :failure then [ 'Failure', true  ]
            end

        email = new_email
        email.subject = "[Backup::%s] #{@model.label} (#{@model.trigger})" % name
        email.body    = @template.result('notifier/mail/%s.erb' % status.to_s)

        if send_log
          email.convert_to_multipart
          email.attachments["#{@model.time}.#{@model.trigger}.log"] = {
            :mime_type => 'text/plain;',
            :content   => Logger.messages.join("\n")
          }
        end

        email.deliver!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup/blob/master/lib/backup/notifier/mail.rb